# Line integral of the divergence of a curve's unit tangent vector.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I've supplied an answer to another question here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222064/line-integration-given-tangent-vector/222205#222205

I'd like somebody more familiar with vector calculus to check as I'm not 100% confident. 
We have a smooth curve $C$ where $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose the tangent vectors of $C$ are always of unit length so $||\alpha'(t)||_2=1$. Typically these would be lines or circles or helices, but what other curves might we expect?

And suppose we have a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ such that $\mathbf{F}[\alpha_x(t),\alpha_y(t),\alpha_z(t)]=\alpha^\prime(t)$ - that is the field $\mathbf{F}$ is *exactly* the unit tangent vector when restricted to the curve $C$.

Then we have the following line integral along $C$:

$$
\int_{C}\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}\ ds = \int_{a}^{b}\nabla\cdot\alpha^\prime(t)||\alpha'(t)||_2 \ dt=\int_{a}^{b}\nabla\cdot\alpha^\prime(t)\ dt
$$

I claim this equals $0$ as there should be no average net flux in/out of an infinitesimal box that travels along the curve. At any point, a unit vector enters and exits the box. Are the next steps below valid or do I need to use the chain-rule on the partial derivatives for substituting $x=\alpha_x(t),y=\alpha_y(t),x=\alpha_z(t)$ ?

$$=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{d \alpha_x}{dt}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{d \alpha_y}{dt}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{d \alpha_z}{dt}dt$$

$$=\frac{d}{d x}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{d \alpha_x}{dt}dt+\frac{d}{d y}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{d \alpha_y}{dt}dt+\frac{d}{d z}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{d \alpha_z}{dt}dt=0+0+0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the closed-loop integral of a divergence is not always zero (it is only the closed-loop integral of the gradient of a scalar function which is always $0$). Here's a simple counter example. Let $F: \Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^3$ be defined by
\begin{align}
F(x,y,z) = (-y,x,z),
\end{align}
and consider the curve $\alpha: [0,2\pi] \to \Bbb{R}^3$ defined by
\begin{align}
\alpha(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, 0).
\end{align}
So, the curve $C$ parametrized by $\alpha$ is the unit circle in the $x$-$y$ plane. It is clear that
\begin{align}
(F \circ \alpha)(t) &= (-\sin t, \cos t, 0) = \alpha'(t),
\end{align}
and that $\lVert \alpha'(t) \rVert = 1$. So, $F$ and $\alpha$ satisfy all of your hypotheses. However, the divergence of $F$ is $1$. So,
\begin{align}
\int_C (\nabla \cdot F)\, ds &= \int_C \, ds = \int_0^{2\pi} \lVert \alpha'(t)\rVert\, dt = 2\pi \neq 0.
\end{align}

---

The biggest flaw in your argument (which I didn't really understand) is that you started talking about the divergence of $\alpha'$, i.e $\nabla \cdot (\alpha')$. This makes no sense, because the divergence is only defined for vector fields which are defined on open subsets of $\Bbb{R}^3$ (i.e for functions of $3$-variables). However, $\alpha'$ is simply a map $[0,2\pi] \to \Bbb{R}^3$, which is a function of one-variable. So, things like $\dfrac{\partial \alpha_1}{\partial x}, \dfrac{\partial \alpha_2}{\partial y}$ etc are not even well-defined objects.

Notice that the correct statement is $F \circ \alpha = \alpha'$, **NOT** $F = \alpha'$. After all, how can a function of $3$-variables be equal to a function of $1$ variable? This is why the step in going from $\nabla \cdot F = \nabla \cdot \alpha'$ is completely wrong; actually it's not just wrong, the RHS isn't even well-defined.

Hopefully this clarifies the situation.

Comment: I see. Then it's technically undefined as there's no correct way to calculate the partial derivatives for $\nabla\cdot F$ in other directions heading offroad the curve because $\alpha^\prime$ takes no values there. Before I accept+award, lets imagine we defined divergence more loosely such that you could calculate it on a line or curve - intuitively the total degree to which the vector field is a source/sink in all applicable directions that stay on the curve. Does it seem reasonable to say this version of the divergence is zero?

Comment: ^  like if you had a 1D vector field $F(x)$ on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and a small interval $I[a,a+\delta]$ then our divergence measures the rate that $F$ enters/exits the interval as $\delta\rightarrow 0$ . This, but with a curve instead of the real line, and curve segment instead of interval explains my argument.

Comment: @flinty that idea of "divergence along a curve" which you describe sounds much more like the integral of a gradient along a curve. Because if you have $f: \Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}$, and you take the gradient $\nabla f$, then $\int_{\gamma} (\nabla f) \cdot \mathbf{dl} = f(\gamma(t_2)) - f(\gamma(t_1))$ measures how much the function changes along the curve as the gradient flows around the curve. In the case of a closed curve it is $0$. Intuitively, $(\nabla f)\cdot \mathbf{dl}$ measures how much the function changes when you move a slightly along the (one and only) direction tangent to the curve.

Comment: I understand the gradient but it's not quite the same concept. I mean the average amount that a vector field (not a scalar) enters or exits a region *(interval, surface patch, curve segment, volume, whatever)* in the limit as the region shrinks and its measure goes to zero. I suppose that would require extending the idea of divergence to more general manifolds than just $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. It's probably worth moving to a new question though.